# What is the best method for browsing android platform source?

Tags: android, editor

I am looking for some software(IDE, editors etc) to browse android platform code. I have downloaded it on my linux machine and I can build it using command-line tools. I am currently doing remote access to the linux machine using putty.
I don't want an IDE but an editor (preferably windows based) using which I can browse code easily(with functions like "go to definition" "go to reference" etc. I tried using notepad++ with some plugins, but I did not find them very mature.

Comment: What do you mean by **browse**? Any text editor can let you read the source. Notepad++ even gives you nice fonts and syntax highlighting. What more do you need?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want an IDE? This is what they're for.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the all familiar eclipse IDE, just download the Android SDK, set it up in eclipse then Copy the source code and paste it into

`..\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-8\sources`

Create the folder if it does not exist. Replace 8 with the corresponding API level for your source code (e.g 9 for Gingerbread).

With the source code in place, pressing F3 over any Android class in eclipse opens the source file and places the cursor over where that class is defined.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is conflicting.

You want to be able to use functions like go to definition and go to reference wich are IDE functions but you don't want an IDE.

An editor is what an editor does best and that is editing.
At most an editor can highlight certain things but it doesn't really understand what is written.

An IDE(Integrated development environment) is what you want.
I recommend Eclipse, it's free and doesn't take much time setting up.
It has all the functions you want and more.
With the project explorer inside eclipse you can easily switch between source files.
Also it has SVN capabilities if you have the correct plugin so you can easily download complete android projects.

I hope this information is what you seek.

Comment: I don't mind using an IDE. Just that I don't want its inbuilt build functionality. That I want to do with commandline. Also, eclipse is very slow. If you have any guide on how to set up eclipse for "android platform development" please let me know.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing . that should help you.

Comment: I think you are still not understanding the question. I am asking for help in android PLATFORM development.(Not in android APPLICATION development). The instructions given there are for app development. I already have that set up. For, platform development the programming is done in C/C++ along with JAVA. So, I need something useful in that as there is very less documentation available from google.

Comment: I see, sorry... then i do not have an awnser.

Answer (score 0):

Consider our [Java Source Code Browser](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Formatters/JavaBrowser.html).  Produces a JavaDoc like result, but hyperlinked to the code and vice versa.  Literally "browse" the code with your, er, browser.

The Java Source Browser tool itself runs on Windows, not linux, but the resulting HTML pages can be put anywhere.

EDIT Feb 2013:  Long since, the Java Source Browser can be run under linux just fine using Wine.